# Populate Outlook body with a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, outlook

I am trying to read some records from a MySQL database and send them via Outlook to my boss.

I searched the internet and found topics for importing data from Excel or Access etc, but nothing about a MySQL query in a PHP project.

Could you please show me a way to follow?

Comment: PHP and Outlook interop seems like a very "interesting" combination...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposedly, [Genius Connect](http://www.geniusconnect.com/geniusconnect.asp) can pump data from MySQL to Outlook, though I haven't tried it personally.

It's an Outlook Add-In toolbar, and there is a free version, limited to 49 records.